# Using Tiered commission structure in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a tiered commission rate based on the number of sales that I cribbed from a couple of Excel Formulas:

```
Min Max Payout  Differential
1   5   $3.00   $3.00
5       $4.00   $1.00
```

Starts at A1 and ends at D3.  Sheet is named Tiered Bonus
On another sheet I have the following program referencing Tiered (row 2):

```
=IF(ISBLANK($A2),"",SUMPRODUCT(--($K2>'Tiered Bonus'!$A$2:$A$3),--($K2-'Tiered Bonus'!$A$2:$A$3),'Tiered Bonus'!$D$2:$D$3))
```

Putting 5 in sales, however, yields only $12 when it should yield $16 (4*3)+(1*4). I know there's something obvious that I am missing but I can't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that A1:D3 is set up this way...

```
Min Max Payout  Differential
0   5   $3.00   $3.00
4       $4.00   $1.00
```

Then, with K2 containing 5, the following formula will return 16...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($K2>$A$2:$A$3),--($K2-$A$2:$A$3),$D$2:$D$3)
```

Note that the calculation takes place this way...

```
(5 - 0) x 3 = 5 x 3 = 15 '$3.00 for anything over 0
(5 - 4) X 1 = 1 x 1 = 1  '$1.00 for anything over 4
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting there, but now it's putting $19 for 5 sales